# How to parse a List inside a Json String In java?

Tags: java, json, list, jsondecoder

**Input Json String:** "{"predicted_route": [1, 351, 371, 372, 373, 0]}" that has been received after making a Post Request call to a backend server.

I would like to extract the List from the JSON String into an ArrayList.

I haven't found anything online that shows how one would go about this?

If I can use org.json that would be the best.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: No, the 2 solutions that I have received will work very well. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.json.*;

String jsonString = inputJsonString; //assign your JSON String here
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("predicted_route");
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
if (jsonArray != null) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { 
        arrayList.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
    } 
}
```

More examples to [parse JSON in Java](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/)

Downloadable jar: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Answer (score 1):

Include [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) dependency so you're able to deserialize the JSON without parsing it manually

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a POJO representation of your object. To have `predicted_route` mapped to the correct field you can annotate it with `@JsonProperty`.

```
class Route {  
  
    @JsonProperty("predicted_route")
    private List<Integer> predictedRoute;  
    
    public List<Integer> getPredictedRoute(){
        return predictedRoute;
    }
    
    public void setPlannedRoute(List<Integer> route){
        this.plannedRoute = route;
    }
}
```

Map the JSON string to your object

```
String yourJson = "{\\"predicted_route\\": [1, 351, 371, 372, 373, 0]}";
Route myRoute = new ObjectMapper().readValue(yourJson, Route.class);

System.out.println(myRoute.getPredictedRoute());
```

Comment: Thanks a ton !! This is a really good solution!